# Extraer datos de usuario en codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeingiter

**Introduccion**

Llevo un par de dias tratando de sacar este dato y no termino de entenderlo, por lo tanto lo voy posponiendo y voy realizando otras cosas. Hoy lo he intentado de nuevo como soy bastante novata en codeigniter desconozco porque ocurre esto o como es que no funciona.

**¿Que es lo que deseo realizar?**

Quiero extraer los datos del usuario en una página desde la función index de mi controlador.

**Descripción**

Tengo un controlador con la siguiente función index():

```
 public function index()
    {
     
     $users = new UserModel();

     $datos['users'] = $users->findAll();

     $dataEmpresa = $users->find('user_enterprise');
    
     return view('panel/home',$datos);

    }
```

Esta funcion se encarga de recorrer el modelo de usuarios con todos los datos de mi tabla "users" y hacerlos accesibles desde esta función.
Tambien he tratado de crear un variable que guarde los datos de las empresas.
Finalmente devuelve a la página deseada es decir la home de mi panel de administración.

La tabla usuarios (llamada **users** en la base de datos) está compuesta por:

> user_id
>
> user_name
>
> user_surname
>
> user_enterprise
>
> user_nif
>
> user_email
>
> user_password
>
> id_rol
>
> user_created_at
>
> user_accept

Ahora por otro lado tenemos la página home (es una view) que se encarga de mostrar el panel de administracion.

En la home que es donde deseo mostrar los datos del usuario que está conectado en ese mismo momento he intentado lo siguiente:

**Caso 1 (Invocar a la variable de session y mostrar los datos):**

Se me ocurrio en llamar a la session pero esta solo muestra algunos datos especificos como el id, el nombre o el email.

Yo necesito extraer todos los datos, los que mas necesito son user_enterprise y user_accept ya que posteriormente necesito compararlos con otros datos.

**Caso 2 (crear unas variables array vacias y crear un bucle y una comparación):**

```
              $session = session();
              $idUser = $session->get('user_id');

              $datass = [];
              $guardoEmpresa=[];

              foreach ($users as $row) {

                $datass = [
                  $row['user_id'],
                  $row['user_name'],
                  $row['user_enterprise'],
                  $row['user_accept']
                ];
                if (in_array($idUser, $datass)) {
                  $guardoEmpresa = in_array($datass[$row['user_enterprise']];
                  $guardoActivacion = $datass[$row['user_accept']]; 
                }
              }
```

Este dato me da error undefined index con el nombre de la empresa que estoy buscando, es decir: Undefined Index NombreEmpresa.
Me muestra los datos que necesito como error.

**Caso 3 (hacer un var_dump para ver los datos):**

```
var_dump($users);
```

Hice un var_dump en el que me mostró todos los datos de los usuarios en un array. si yo llamo a la variable  $users["user_id"];   para mostrar el id me dice ErrorException
Undefined index: user_id.
He de imaginar que la unica forma de extraerlo es con un bucle que recorra todos los datos, ya que esta variable guarda todos los datos de la tabla.

=============================================================

Así que la verdad que no tengo ni idea de como extraer mi dato de empresa actual con el usuario que tengo la session iniciada en ese momento. Si que es verdad que en otras páginas puedo mostrar el usuario de ese momento ya que se le pasa un id a la dirección del buscador y a la función por lo tanto es mas sencillo, sin este dato lo unico que se me ocurria era comparar el array de usuarios con el id de session actual y extraer el resultado, pero no soy capaz. Me podríais ayudar? gracias.

=============================================================

**EDIT:**

Al final como explico en el parrafo anterior para hacerlo funcionar realicé un montón de cambios en el código para adaptarlo todo nuevamente y poderle pasar un id de usuario a través de la url en la ruta y en la funcion recoger el id del usuario.

En base a esto, pude extraer los datos y seguí con mi web, pero sigo teniendo la duda de si hay mas modos de poder realizar esto, alguien me sabría decir? solo está este modo?